# How to convert ontology from DAML to OWL

Tags: ontology, owl, protege

I'm trying to convert [this](http://www.lgi2p.ema.fr/~ranwezs/ontologies/musicV1.0.daml) DAML ontology into OWL (or any other supported by Protege) format. I found an [online converter](http://www.mindswap.org/2002/owl.shtml), but the attempt of opening the result of conversion by protege entailed the following error message:

```
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.syntax.RDFParserException: [line=21:column=39] IRI '#To Interpret' cannot be resolved against curent base IRI file:/home/citxx/Downloads/musicV1.0.xml
```

[There](http://pastebin.com/e4Hz2LQM) is the result of conversion.

What is wrong with the mentioned converter? Or is there another ways of conversion DAML ontologies into Protege-compatible format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things, spaces can't be in the rdf:ID unless they are escaped, those have to end up forming valid URI's.  Also, it doesnt look like there's a defined xml base in that file, which  is also a problem.

You might be better off just doing the conversion by hand, its a very basic ontology, and it would not take you long to recreate it in Protege.